# When do I need roads?

Tags: anno-1404

Easy question: Who needs roads to which location in Anno 1404?

Here is what I know:

- Warehouses need roads to grab the finished goods from the industries.
- People houses need roads for the sake of having them: If people have
  no roads the "can't" reach the marketplace (for companionship). But
  when having roads, they walk across the grassland to the market instead
  of using the roads they demanded.

**What other buildings need roads to function at all and where must the roads lead to?**

For example: Is there any benefit if each building is connected to a single road network so that theoretically each building can be reached by road from any starting point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've covered the two main reasons for building roads: connecting market buildings (or the warehouse) to production buildings, and connecting houses to a marketplace / bazaar. You also need a road connection between houses and other support buildings such as a church or mosque.

I can't think of any advantage of having a large road network, since market buildings can only collect products from production buildings within a certain radius anyway.

You do not necessarily need a road connection between intermediate production buildings and market buildings.

For example, you do not always need a road between your Hemp Plantation and market building: if you build your Weaver's Hut close enough (within the highlighted radius) to the Hemp Plantation, the weavers will automatically take the hemp they need. You still need a road connection from the Weaver's Hut to a market building to collect the finished product.

If you do build a road to the Hemp Plantation, however, you will be able to store hemp in your warehouse, which may be useful for stocking up excess, or if you need it for a quest.